# Is there an easy way to add multiple javascript images together via `imgCounter.src =`

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

In photoshop I created images 0.png thru 9.png and know I can change each digit to simulate a counter by changing each picture of each digit as it counts down.

**IDEA 1:**

One way I thought would be to have multiple lines of

**HTML:**

```
<div align="right"><img src="graphics/odometers/1.png" /id="digit1">
                   <img src="graphics/odometers/2.png" /id="digit2">
                   <img src="graphics/odometers/3.png" /id="digit3"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var imgCounter = document.getElementById('digit1');
imgCounter.src = "graphics/odometers/white and blue with black background/1.png"; // shows the digit 1
var imgCounter = document.getElementById('digit2');
imgCounter.src = "graphics/odometers/white and blue with black background/2.png"; // shows the digit 2
// etc for as many digits as I want to show
```

and change the digits in javascript by each ID.  It's not hard but for flexibility can I have 1 image ID and string 3 .png's together in javascript?  Like this...

**IDEA 2**: *Not sure if this is possible.*

**HTML:**

```
<div align="right"><img src="" /id="formtimer"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
// somehow show 3 graphics in a row 123 without having 3 ID tags, only 1 ID tag
var imgCounter = document.getElementById('formtimer');
imgCounter.src = "graphics/odometers/white and blue with black background/1.png";
```

I know the example above only shows the digit 1 and doesn't do all 3 digits...   (because I don't know if it's possible).

Is there a way to display 3 pictures together? lol.  Easily?  I know anything can technically be done the hard way...

If it's a big pain in the butt I'm ok with IDEA 1 but it's less "freedom" because I have to encode the HTML with multiple ID tags which is tedius...

Just curious what you all think and if you have a solution.  :)  Much appreciated.

**ALSO:**

Is it ok to leave the `img src=""` as a NULL or empty string if I'll later be sticking an image in via javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include the `<img>` elements in the source html at all, you can add them with JavaScript and not even give them ids.

At the point in your source where you want the counter just put an empty div with an appropriate id.

When the `counterSet()` function below is called with the id of the container div and a value it creates new child `<img>` elements in the div with src set appropriately, but reuses any existing child `<img>` elements that are there from any previous value that was set. If the new value has fewer digits than the last than the function removes the leftover `<img>` elements:

```
<div id="counter1"></div>

<script>
function counterSet(counterId, val) {
   var c = document.getElementById(counterId),
       i,
       d;
   for (i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
       // if the container already had enough child img elements
       // for current digit set current img's src, otherwise add
       // new img to end
       if (i < c.childNodes.length)
          c.childNodes[i].src = "graphics/odometers/" + val.charAt(i) + ".png";
       else {
          d = document.createElement("img");
          d.src = "graphics/odometers/" + val.charAt(i) + ".png";
          c.appendChild(d);
       }
   }
   // if the container already had too many child img elements
   // (from a previous value) remove the leftover digits
   while (c.childNodes.length > val.length)
       c.removeChild(c.childNodes[val.length]);   
}

counterSet("counter1","218");

</script>
```

Comment: Cool - I'll check that out in a bit (just got home) - it looks like what I was looking for!  If it works HUGE thanks!  I'll come back and give you credit once I try it out.  See... thats what I lack - I don't know what is possible because I don't understand the DOM fully yet and what is allowed and what isn't.  Without that knowledge I'm still a novice programmer.  I understand how nodes work but not in crawling the DOM (a website with a picture of the DOM "tree" would be awesome) but I know a tad Visual C/C++ and have worked with linked lists.  I can't wait to digest and study your example!

Comment: Your example works perfectly!  Also, thank you for the extra insight into how the DOM works.   MUCH appreciated!  Nice clear example.  I LOVE learning!  THANK YOU!

Comment: You're welcome. There are lots of DOM tutorials (as I'm sure you'll see if you use Google), but offhand I can't recommend any particular one. This one seems OK as an intro: http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/javascript/synd/2001/08/17/DOM-2.html

Answer (score 0):

I would just use three separate ids.

You can use something like this to set the src attributes:

```
for (i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_IMAGES; i++) {
  var img = document.getElementById('img_' + i);
  imgr.src = 'images/image_' + i + '.png";
)
```